# How to write sub-queries within case in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like this

```
jjsc_job_no jjsc_from_status jjsc_time           jjsc_wf_userid
123456      D                2012-07-01 13:33:27 804
123456      E                2014-04-08 03:22:35 804
123457      D                2012-07-01 13:33:27 805
123457      E                2014-04-08 03:22:35 806
```

I want a result where if `jjsc_from_status = 'E'` then check if the same job when `jjsc_from_status = 'D'` had a different `jjsc_wf_userid`. If so then return `3` if not `0`

I wrote something like this but says syntax error

```
select case jjsc_from_status 
                    when 'E' then if(select jjsc_from_status from jdwf_job_status_cycle where jjsc_wf_userid = jjsc_wf_userid, 0,3 )
                    when 'D' then 9                     
                    end as estimatedunits
                    from jdwf_job_status_cycle 
                    where jjsc_time>='$fDate' and jjsc_time<='$tDate'
                    order by jjsc_time
```

Expected result is

```
estimatedunits
9
0
9
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a nested CASE and EXISTS:

```
select 
  case j.jjsc_from_status 
    when 'D' then 9
    when 'E' then 
      case 
        when exists (
          select 1 from jdwf_job_status_cycle 
          where jjsc_job_no = j.jjsc_job_no and jjsc_from_status = 'D' 
          and jjsc_wf_userid <> j.jjsc_wf_userid)
        then 3 
        else 0 
      end 
  end as estimatedunits
from jdwf_job_status_cycle j 
where jjsc_time>='$fDate' and jjsc_time<='$tDate'
order by jjsc_time
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d2wP1pqx3uW7peAig3Na9w/1)(without the WHERE clause).
Results:

```
| estimatedunits |
| -------------- |
| 9              |
| 0              |
| 9              |
| 3              |
```

Answer (score 1):

You should ALWAYS use alias for your tables!

In this case you want to use data from the drive table in the sub-query, so put 2 different alias for them:

```
select 
    case jsc.jjsc_from_status 
        when 'E' then if(exists(select jjsc_from_status from jdwf_job_status_cycle jsc2 where jsc2.jjsc_job_no = jsc.jjsc_job_no and jsc2.jjsc_from_status = 'D' and jsc2.jjsc_wf_userid <> jsc.jjsc_wf_userid), 3, 0)
        when 'D' then 9
    end as estimatedunits
from jdwf_job_status_cycle jsc
where jsc.jjsc_time>='$fDate' and jsc.jjsc_time<='$tDate'
order by jsc.jjsc_time
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error cause is from placing `select` that returns a string into `if` clause, you should modify the query within the `if` clause to return a boolean result, something like:

```sql
select case jjsc_from_status 
                    when 'E' then if( (select count(jjsc_from_status) from jdwf_job_status_cycle as t2 where t1.jjsc_wf_userid = t2.jjsc_wf_userid) > 0, 0,3 )
                    when 'D' then 9                     
                    end as estimatedunits
                    from jdwf_job_status_cycle as t1
                    where jjsc_time>='$fDate' and jjsc_time<='$tDate'
                    order by jjsc_time
```

Comment: still it would be ambiguous: jjsc_wf_userid = jjsc_wf_userid

Comment: you are right, semantically it is wrong but from syntax wise this condition is correct, and it will be always true as it compares the two values from the sub-select query.  I updated the query to include aliases as well